# How to know when pushViewController is over?

Tags: ios, animation

I'm doing this to push a new controller:

```
[navController pushViewController:addEventViewC animated:YES];
[_addView setHidden:true];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addEventFloat"];
[_addButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The problem is that the image is changed during the animation, and I would prefer to change it AFTER the animation.

Do you know how I could proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may take a look at the delegate of your `UINavigationController`: `navigationController:didSHowViewController:animated:`, or maybe do you changes in `viewDidDisappear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in: `-viewDidDisappear:` method.